# how to fetch checkboxes value with checkboxes in php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="form-check col-lg-6 offset-4 mt-3">
        Size:
        <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="XS" name="size[]">XS
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="S" name="size[]">S
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="M" name="size[]">M
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="L" name="size[]">L
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="XL" name="size[]">XL
            </label>
        </div>
        
    </div>
```

This is the checkboxes and I want to fetch these checkboxes value with checkboxes from database.
Checkboxes value are already store through implode function, now I want to fetch checkboxes data with checkboxes also.

```
<?php
                        $check_arr=array();
                        $size = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM store");
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($size) > 0){
                            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($size);
                            $check_arr = explode(",",$result['size']);
                          }
                          $size_arr = array("XS","S","M","L","XL");
                          foreach($size_arr as $sizes){
                      
                            $checked = "";
                            if(in_array($sizes,$check_arr)){
                              $checked = "checked";
                            }
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="size[]" value="'.$sizes.'" '.$checked.' > '.$sizes.' <br/>';
                          }
                          ?>
```

In this above PHP code data is shown but checkboxes isn't appeared.

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking how to populate the checkboxes with existing data from your database?

Comment: yes.. How  can I do it?

Comment: Well, where exactly are you stuck? You can set the value of a checkbox in the HTML by adding the `checked` attribute to it. So if you're generating the HTML from a php script it would be fairly easy. But I don't know the context of how your backend works so I can't be specific.

Comment: Kindly check question again I haveupdate it

Comment: Unless your query crashes, that code should produce 6 checkboxes. Have you debugged it? What is the raw HTML output like? Are there any PHP or mysqli errors?